# Load jquery and google map

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, load

Hello im using load jquery to refresh my page  each second the problem came when i added a google map in this page the map is appear and disappear in each second is there anyway to correct this issue

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            $id = '&id='.$_GET['id'];
        }
     if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['c']) || isset($_GET['c'])){
            $id = '&id='.$_GET['id'].'&c='.$_GET['c'];
        }*/
    ?>

     $("#pub").load("./ajax.php?act=pharmacie<?php echo $id; ?>");
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#pub").load("./ajax.php?act=pharmacie<?php echo $id; ?>");
    },1000);


});
```

this the div which i load my script

```
  <div id="pub"></div>
```

and the last one is my main script "ajax.php" contains the code of google map

```
        <div id="pharma-title">
            <table width="100%" id="tableNom">

                <td width="40%" id="hero">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0">
```

Comment: Show code or what you tried so far,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, refreshing your site every second is a bad idea, second, your problem is that google maps  can't load that fast, so you get that "Blinking" effect.

If you still want to refresh your site every second, edit your code so the google maps wont refresh every second.

P.S tell me why are you refreshing your site every second, maybe there's an easy way to do what u want without refreshing every second.

Comment: i have a public page which display ads and i want to make changes on this ads without reload the page...is there any solution without using this load jquery

Answer (score 0):

you do not want to reload jquery. what you want to do is update the part you wanted to change every second.
let me know what you are trying to do with the relevant html/jquery code and i will be happy to help you.

Comment: i have a public page which display ads and i want to make changes on this ads without reload the page...is there any solution without using this load jquery

Comment: yes. you want to make an affect on the div or class with the ads in them. you did not mention exactly how it works. so its hard for me to give you better pointers then that.